# Call a Function Handler after Owin Token Authorization in C#

Tags: c#, owin

I use Owin on serverside to get access token. Afterwards, I send the token from client to the server to be authenticated. I want to know, how can I run a function exactly after authorization was completed? (I've tried AccessTokenProvider -> OnReceiveAsync but it didn't not worked properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. It's enough using OnReceive  instead of OnReceiveAsync in App Start or where you initiate Oauth Object, like the below:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
     TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/GetAuthToken",
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin",
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            AccessTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider()
            {
                OnReceive = context =>
                {
                    context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
                    // After this you can be sure that your ticket is initialized and have
                    // an access to the user
                    if(context.Ticket.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        EntityContext.UserId = context.Ticket.Identity.GetUserId();
                    else
                        EntityContext.UserId = "";
                }
            }
};
```